# MySQL query to return most used tags via pivot table

Tags: mysql, tags, pivot

I have 3 tables:

```
threads (thread_id and thread_title)
tags (tag_id and tag_name)
tag_thread (pivot only with thread_id and tag_id)
```

How can I formulate a query that gives me the names of the 5 tags that occur the most times in the latest 100 entries?

Comment: Make it the 3 tags that occur the most times in the latest 5 entries, and see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the top 5 tags of the latest 100 threads

```
select ta.tag_name
from tags ta 
join tag_thread tt on tt.tag_id = ta.tag_id
join 
(
   select * from threads order by thread_id desc limit 100
) th on tt.thread_id = th.thread_id
group by ta.tag_name
order by count(tt.thread_id) desc
limit 5
```

Comment: awesome, works like a charm, thank you so much! there is only one little mistake in line 2: should be "tags t"

Comment: thanks again! there is one more thing I can't get my head around now. I would like to have an optional parameter $tagId. If $tagId is given, the result of the query should filter for tags that are used by threads that use the tag with $tagId. Any idea how to do that as well?

Comment: That is possible but a whole different query. If you can't get it to work ask another question about it.